# How to stop FN key changing my keyboard layout (macOS Big Sur)?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I've got my new MacBook Air m1 very recently. I changed default behaviour of F-keys to normal F1, F2, etc. So in order to activate 'media' keys like volume up/down I need to press Fn+F-key. Now, what I've realised is that pressing Fn with F1, F2, etc sometimes (50/50 chance) changes the keyboard layout as well! God, it is so annoying. It shouldn't be so 100%. I think that's just a bug. So, how can I disable Fn for changing my keyboard layout?

Comment: There is a box for making Fn/Globe change keyboards in system preferences > keyboard which you should uncheck.  Have you done that?

Comment: God! I missed it at the very surface of the section! Just put your comment as solution :))) Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This new feature of MacOS Big Sur can be turned off by unchecking a box in System Preferences > Keyboard.

Comment: Set Press FN key to "Do Nothing". If it's already at "Do Nothing" select something else, then select it again.

Comment: Thank goodness for this response. As Tom replied to the original question, it's the "globe" symbol in the panel, doesn't say anything about FN. I spent an embarrassing amount of time before realizing this.

Comment: @Luke Any machine before late 2020 doesn't have a globe key, it just says Fn, so it can be confusing.

Comment: @TomGewecke You're talking about the physical keyboards, right (I still use 10 year old magic keyboards that are fn)? I was talking about the preferences pane itself, which only admits globes exist. The whole thing is definitely a confusing mess.

Comment: @Luke On my Monterey install, the pref pane says "Press fn key to (popup menu with 4 choices)." No globe.

Comment: @TomGewecke So weird, both of my Monterrey 12.1 installs only say "Press [globe] to [menu]". Thanks apple... :/

Comment: @passsy 's answer worked for me

Answer (score 17):

I felt a screenshot may be helpful here.
See this place in **System Preferences -> Keyboard** to stop the Globe/<kbd>fn</kbd> key from switching keyboards—change it to **Do Nothing**. It still works as expected for the <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, ... keys, and Home/End functionality (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, etc).

The below screenshot is for macOS Monterey, earlier versions of macOS may look slightly different.

[image: screenshot of System Preferences > Keyboard on Monterey]

The below screenshot is for macOS Ventura, different visual but same function and location (**System Settings > Keyboard**).

[image: screenshot of System Settings > Keyboard on Ventura]

Comment: thank you, I have not realised that "globe" sign is "fn", but thanks to your screenshot finally it woks.

Comment: You can do it in console too: `defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist 'AppleFnUsageType' -int 0`

Answer (score 5):

For people using Mac os Ventura, to deactivate the effects and FN keys,
Go to system settings and keyboard shortcuts.
[image]

Go to the function keys and activate the toggle like the image below.
[image]

Now go to the Mission Control tab and uncheck the F keys
[image]

So it's done now you can use the regular fn keys.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS **Ventura:**

 > **System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Press  key to** --> **Do Nothing**
[image: Settings]